# Converting large SVG to PNG file

Tags: svg, inkscape, image-conversion

So I have a 16mb SVG file with about 30,000 nodes and I've been trying to convert it to a 10,000x10,000 png image. I tried a lot of stuff and the closest I got was with inkscape, but it got some weird error halfway through the command and only rendered half the image. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: What error message did you get?  There is no way determine what steps might solve the problem (other application or otherwise) without knowing what problem inkscape encountered.

Comment: Well heres what happens when I try it: http://puu.sh/2lgCO

Comment: (note I removed your request for a product recommendation to avoid it being closed as off topic)

Comment: What version are you running?  Older versions got this issue through memory usage, but given the size of the output, it may be that you are just coming up against a lack of memory.

Comment: Its version 0.48.4 I think, I downloaded it like a hour ago. By the way I have 16gb of 1688mhz ram but apparently its not using that at all, might there be a way to tell inkscape to use more ram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a dedicated command line tool for converting and manipulating images, so may product better results:

```
convert -density 1200 -resize 10000x10000 your.svg your.png
```

You may need to change the density command to get optimal results

Comment: Well I tried this and it worked except the resulting image is like really fuzzy and low-res. Its also 208mb which is a bit big.

Comment: @user209128 It can take a bit of trial and error to get good results, try the change above.