# ImageMagick Convert: How to produce sharp resized PNG files from SVG files?

Tags: macos, imagemagick, png, svg

I am using this command to generate a sharp 512px wide version of an SVG file that I have:

```
convert -geometry 256 pinterest.svg pinterest.png
```

This is the source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" enable-background="new 0 0 16 16" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#231F20" d="M8,0C3.582,0,0,3.582,0,8c0,3.275,1.97,6.09,4.789,7.327c-0.022-0.559-0.005-1.229,0.139-1.837
        c0.154-0.649,1.029-4.359,1.029-4.359s-0.255-0.51-0.255-1.266c0-1.186,0.687-2.071,1.542-2.071c0.729,0,1.08,0.547,1.08,1.201
        c0,0.73-0.467,1.825-0.707,2.838c-0.2,0.85,0.426,1.541,1.262,1.541c1.515,0,2.537-1.947,2.537-4.253
        c0-1.753-1.181-3.066-3.329-3.066c-2.427,0-3.938,1.81-3.938,3.831c0,0.697,0.205,1.188,0.528,1.57
        C4.824,9.631,4.845,9.7,4.792,9.902c-0.039,0.147-0.126,0.502-0.163,0.643c-0.054,0.202-0.218,0.274-0.401,0.199
        C3.11,10.289,2.59,9.064,2.59,7.688c0-2.272,1.916-4.997,5.718-4.997c3.053,0,5.065,2.21,5.065,4.582
        c0,3.139-1.746,5.482-4.317,5.482c-0.864,0-1.677-0.467-1.955-0.996c0,0-0.464,1.844-0.562,2.199
        c-0.17,0.616-0.502,1.232-0.805,1.713C6.452,15.885,7.213,16,8,16c4.418,0,8-3.582,8-8S12.418,0,8,0z"/>
</svg>
```

However it produces a blurry PNG:

## [image: Pinterest]

As my source is a vector illustration, I was expecting to get a sharp image. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: The problem is the `width="16px" height="16px"` in the SVG file. Try changing the ImageMagick command to `convert -resize 3200% pinterest.svg pinterest.png` for a 512x512 image. Not sure if you'll need a `-geometry 512` too or not.

Comment: That didn't work either. I tried it with and without `-geometry`. It produces a blurry image. Even `-density` doesn't work. However I managed to achieve my desired results using Apache Batik.

Comment: A slightly different approach might be something like what is described in this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/569235/57398).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but I sort of went around it by setting the density first.

From command line:

```
for %f in (*.svg) do (convert -antialias -background transparent -density 600 -resize 1024x1024 %f %~nf.png)
```

Comment: How did you choose that specific density value?

Answer (score 2):

```
convert -density 3072 pinterest.svg pinterest.png
```

Because the original DPI is 96 and the pixel size is 16x16, so 512/16*96 is 3072.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to solve this issue using ImageMagick, but Apache Batik's rasterize script can be used to convert and resize the SVG to PNG in a lossless fashion.

```
java -jar batik-rasterizer.jar samples/batikFX.svg
```

See [here](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html) for more information.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but it really doesn't make sense to call a conversion from vector to raster graphics "lossless" -- an image file is a completely different representation and will always be an approximation of the graphics defined in vector format.

Answer (score 0):

**Use inkscape instead**

Since it does not seem possible to easily determine the `-density` value without a bit more scripting, as also confirmed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853325/how-to-convert-a-svg-to-a-png-with-imagemagick I recommend just using `inkscape` instead, which does that for you:

```
inkscape -w 512 -h 512 -b FFF -e main.png main.svg
```

Output:

[image]

Tested on Inkscape 0.92.5, Ubuntu 20.04.